# Hourly wind turbine electricity/power production data for single installations in the UK?

Tags: data-request, weather, uk, time-series, energy

I'd like to check my wind speed calculated yield against actual yield. Ideally, I would like to know:

- Turbine location
- Turbine model details
- Hourly yield (or other small timestamp)

I've found helpful answers referring to this French resource: https://opendata-renewables.engie.com. But one or more datasets of turbine output data for the UK would be really helpful, if anyone knows of such a resource.  Thank you.